# Primefaces dropdown icon alignment?

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

Hi guys I have a menu bar with submenu bars, but the icon if  a submenu exists is shown above. I want to set the icon right from the menu field. So i hope anyone can help. Here you can see a picture :  https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8yqq7d2mirj0cq/bar.JPG. Sry for the bad quality of the image.

I am using JSF 2.1, primefaces 3.5 and a jquery theme from primefaces .

Menubar

```
<p:menubar styleClass="affaires"   style="position: absolute !important; bottom: 0px !important; vertical-align: bottom !important; list-style: none; width: 100%; text-align: center;"  >
            <p:menuitem value="Home" url="#"/>

            <p:submenu  label="Company">
                <p:menuitem  value="Create Company" url="#"/>
                <p:menuitem   value="Show Companies" url="companies.xhtml"/>
            </p:submenu>

            <p:submenu  label="Taskbox" >
                <p:menuitem value="Inbox" url="taskbox.xhtml"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Sent" url="#"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Trash" url="#"/>
                <p:menuitem value="New Message" url="#"/>
            </p:submenu>

            <p:submenu label="#{loginBean.user.USER_NAME}" >
                <p:menuitem value="Logbook" url="#"/>
                <p:submenu label="Settings" url="#">
                    <p:menuitem value="Account" url="#"/>
                    <p:menuitem value="Contact" url="#"/>
                </p:submenu>
                <p:menuitem value="Logout" url="#"/>
            </p:submenu>

            <p:submenu label="Administration" icon="">
                <p:menuitem value="Users" url="#"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Edit Help" url="#"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Edit GTC" url="#"/>
            </p:submenu>    

            <p:menuitem value="Help" url="#"/>  

    </p:menubar>
```

theme.css

```
 .affaires .ui-menuitem-text{ color:black;}

 .affaires .ui-menu-child{background: white;}

 ul li.ui-menuitem-active>a{
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color:red !important;    
}

li ul li.ui-menuitem-active>a{
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color:green !important;    
}
```

Comment: Attach the generated html, please

Comment: ok i have add it above

Comment: `<p:menubar>...` is not generated html. I mean html you get in browser .

Comment: Drobpox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kvnn68qeh77uu6/gen%20html.txt

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution

Configure the following tag in the theme.css

```
/* left-aligned */
.ui-menu .ui-icon {
  top: .2em;
  left: .2em;
}
```